# UWP Window navigated to (activated) event

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, win-universal-app

I want an event that fires when I have been away from the app and then I navigate back to the window.  Like the Activated event of WPF.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `Window.Current.Activated`.

Comment: Just worth to mention that this event will also be fired in some more cases - like after *MessageDialog*.

Comment: Or when the window is [**Deactivated**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.core.corewindow.activated.aspx)!

Comment: Yeah, this can be differentiated with event's args. The OP may also think about *Window.VisibilityChanged* - this one seems to be fired in less cases. Though everything may also depend if the case concerns mobile/desktop/tablet.

Comment: Activated was the better option, as my use case is that the user is away, doing something else on another app (my window isn't minimized) and then the user comes back, and I want to refresh some data.